# PIN code login for Chrome App - How to implement

Tags: php, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-os

I am looking to make a Chrome App (to run on ChromeOS) that uses a PIN code system to allow the user access to their content that is located on a companion web application.

The idea is to display a PIN code on the ChromeOS app, which the user enters on a specific page of the web application. The ChromeOS app would then pick that up and show content related to that user.

I have a rough idea of how to make it work, but I was wondering firstly, what name is given to this kind of authentication/login and secondly, is there a "proper" way to implement it?

The ChromeOS app is HTML5 of course, and the web app I have is PHP based.